# Unexpected custom init method behaviour of NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit

I would like to create an instance of a subclass of NSManagedObject on the simple way: `Library *library = [[Library alloc] init]` so I overrode `init` method like this.

```
- (instancetype)init
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] 
                               initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    managedObjectContext.parentContext = [RKManagedObjectStore 
                                      defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

   NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Library" 
                                       inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

   self = [super initWithEntity:entityDescription  
                  insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

   return self;
}
```

In a view I create new instance with `Library *library = [[Library alloc] init]` and this is working pretty good. Now I need to add a `Book` object to the `Library` which is in a relationship with it. So a new `Book` instance should be in the same `managedObjectContext` with its parent — `Library`. To instantiate `Book` properly I need to obtain `Library`'s managedObjectContent: `[library managedObjectContent]` gives `nil` back. After hours and hours, I've got a workaround:

```
- (instancetype)init
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [GTObjectManager newManagedObjectContext];

   NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"City" 
                                       inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];

   self =  [super initWithEntity:entityDescription  
                  insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

   return self;
}
```

And in GTObjectManager I have simply the same code as it was in the old init method:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)newManagedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] 
                               initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    managedObjectContext.parentContext = [RKManagedObjectStore 
                                      defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
   return managedObjectContext;
}
```

Now after instantiating `Library *library = [[Library alloc] init]` calling `[library managedObjectContext]` returns not `nil`. So to clarify: if `managedObjectContext` gets created in `init` method, I'm unable to get it after instantiating. If `managedObjectContent` gets created outside of `init` method, I'm able to get it after instantiating.

I can't explain the behaviour. Is it a behaviour of a `init` method? I'm using ARC, is it some kind of ARC behaviour?

Comment: First explain why you insist on using `init` here, because that's the wrong way to do things with Core Data. You're going out of your way to make things hard on yourself-- why?

Comment: I'm implementing a framework, which should give a user some kind of abstraction over objects coming from REST service and/or Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***In your first*** `init` function, you create a local `managedObjectContext` object and use that to create the managed object. *Managed objects do not retain their context*, so `managedObjectContext` is the only strong reference to the object. ARC adds code to release this reference at the end of the function, and since it is the only reference, the managed object context is deallocated.

You can observe this behaviour if you add the following code to your `init` function (after `self = [super initWithEntity:...]`):

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self managedObjectContext]);
// Output: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x100134a00>
managedObjectContext = nil;
NSLog(@"%@", [self managedObjectContext]);
// Output: (null)
```

As you can see, asking a managed object for its context returns `nil` if the context has been deallocated.

***In your second*** `init` function, exactly the same should happen, and I observed exactly the same behavior in my test program. But this depends on how the utility method to return the new context is called.

In your code example, it is called `newManagedObjectContext`. Methods starting with `new...` return a *retained* object, and this is released at the end of the init function. So there should be no difference between your two `init` functions.

However, if the utility method is called e.g. `getManagedObjectContext`, then it returns (roughly speaking) an *autoreleased* object. This object might exist longer, until the current autorelease pool is destroyed.

Perhaps this explains why your code seems to work if the context is created in an utility method.

***Conclusion:*** It does not make sense to create a local temporary context to create objects if you need the objects later. Managed objects live in a context, and if the context is destroyed, you cannot use the objects anymore.

You have to decide first which context you want to use, and then create the objects and their relationships in that context.

Comment: Thanks, one of my conjectures was in that direction.

Comment: And right, my method has a name `getManagedObjectContext`, not `newManagedObjectContext`. So `managedObjectContent` I get from this method will exist until the autorelease pool of the `getManagedObjectContext` destroyed or until the autorelease pool of the method in which I create `Library` destroyed?

Comment: @speechkey: So this was a good guess! - The Clang/ARC documentation about [Unretained return values](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#unretained-return-values) guarantees only that `getManagedObjectContext` returns an object that is valid when the function has returned. This could be an autoreleased object, but this is an implementation detail. You should not rely on that.